# DirectoryAttribute value should be integer instead of string

Tags: c#, ldap

I'm trying to get LDAP authentication working using the .NET `System.DirectoryServices.Protocol` namespace.  (This is necessary as I simply cannot get my existing code using `System.DirectoryServices` to communicate with our client's LDAP server.)

I've managed to get everything working, with the exception that when I try and return the `userAccountControl` attribute for the user account, it is returning a string representation of the value, when it should be returning an integer.  (The value in the Active Directory is definitely an integer.)

In the following code, if I breakpoint at `userAccountFlags = (int)attrib[0];` the type of `attrib[0]` is a string.  Why?

(I can easily "fix" it by replacing it with `int.TryParse((string)attrib[0], out userAccountFlag);` but would prefer to know why it's happening than use this work-around.)

```
var ident = new LdapDirectoryIdentifier(domain, (ssl ? 636 : 389));
using (var conn = new LdapConnection(ident))
{
    conn.Credential = new NetworkCredential(domainUsername, domainPassword);
    conn.AuthType = AuthType.Basic;
    if (ssl)
    {
        conn.SessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer = true;
        conn.SessionOptions.VerifyServerCertificate = (connection, certificate) => true;
    }
    conn.Bind();

    var request = new proto.SearchRequest(rootDN, testDN, SearchScope.Subtree);
    request.Attributes.Add("userAccountControl");
    request.SizeLimit = 1;

    var response = (SearchResponse)conn.SendRequest(request);
    if (response.Entries.Count != 0)
    {
        int userAccountFlags = int.MinValue;
        foreach (proto.SearchResultEntry entry in response.Entries)
        {
            foreach (proto.DirectoryAttribute attrib in entry.Attributes.Values)
            {
                if (attrib.Name == "userAccountControl" && attrib.Count > 0)
                {
                    // The following line breaks, as "attrib[0] is string = true"
                    userAccountFlags = (int)attrib[0];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values returned from the attribute will always be either a string or byte array.

From the documentation of the [DirectoryAttribute indexer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.protocols.directoryattribute.item(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The Get method of Item always attempts to convert and return the value object as a string; otherwise it returns a byte array.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that Daniel is correct.

For attributes like "userAccountControl" and "msDS-User-Account-Control-Computed" which you expect to be an integer, the returned DirectoryAttribute is a bunch of bytes of a string!

Once you cast the bytes back to a string, you can then try parse it to an int.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Microsoft sends back ints as a string in byte form on DirectoryAttribute
    /// Because of that, we must convert bytes to string, and try to parse string to int.
    /// </summary>
    private static int TryGetAttributeValueAsInt(ref IEnumerable<DirectoryAttribute> resultAttrs, string propName)
    {
        int value = 0;
        string sInteger = TryGetAttributeValueAsString(ref resultAttrs, propName);

        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sInteger))
        {
            //We will try to parse the string to an int
            if(!int.TryParse(sInteger, out value))
            {
                //Unable to parse string to int, set value to 0
                value = 0;
            }
        }

        return value;
    }

    private static string TryGetAttributeValueAsString(ref IEnumerable<DirectoryAttribute> resultAttrs, string propName)
    {
        string value = "";
        DirectoryAttribute da = resultAttrs.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Name.Equals(propName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
        if (da != null && da.Count > 0)
        {
            value = da[0] as string;
        }
        return value;
    }
```